# What all techniques and best practices I should use or improve for these photos?

Tags: lighting, aperture, shutter-speed, iso

I am beginner in photography.

These two photos are taken in manual mode and I feel it's perfect shot. Please have a look and let me what all things I should improve and what I shouldn't consider.

What you think about these photos? (techniques and best practices)

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's no such thing as a perfect photo.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't follow the guidelines for "What topics can I ask about" at http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Specifically, it asks for general critiques discussed in detail here: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2039/can-we-re-open-the-door-to-something-a-little-like-photo-critique

Comment: My main concern about "techniques and best practices" what all thinks I can improve for this phot?

Comment: What aspect of those shots do you wish to improve? You need to be very specific. Exposure? Composition? Focus accuracy? Depth of Field? Dynamic range? Color accuracy? Etc.

Comment: I am beginner. I know these terms but I don't know what aspect should improve :(

Comment: Can you please edit your question title and text to distinguish this question from any other question about improving a photograph?

Answer (score 3):

What you need to improve is your own analysis.

The photos probably are ok for one reason, the birds are there and you probably have little time to take the shoot. Any change could mean that you loose the shoot.

> I feel it's perfect shot.

But if you close your own doors and you are self-congratulatory you have reached your own peak.

Michael Clark made some questions.

> What aspect of those shots do you wish to improve? You need to be very specific. Exposure? Composition? Focus accuracy? Depth of Field? Dynamic range? Color accuracy? Etc. – Michael Clark

Make a methodology to ask yourself questions.

Some technical, some composition, some narrative, some inspirational.

Answer (score 0):

As Rafael has pointed out, the birds are not going to pose for your camera, so you got to take the shot quickly when they arrive. What you can try to do is exposure bracketing, usually the bird will be quite a bit darker than the background. The pictures should then be combined into a HDR picture using masking methods, because the bird will move a bit during the exposure bracketing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as composition goes, the first photo has a lot of good things: diagonals, good color contrast, the dark head of the pigeon is framed by the light blue background, there are interesting shadows etc.

The myna shot is a more interesting pose of the bird itself, but the background is distracting.  The white walls at the edges draw the eye away from the bird, and the bird's dark head has a dark wall behind it so the bird doesn't stand out very well.

The main thing I'd recommend from looking at these two shots is to be careful about your backgrounds.